# Mixlib::ShellOut - timeout

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am trying to use Mixlib::ShellOut to execute commands under ruby_block inside a chef recipe.
In Some situations, we cannot complete the task in 600 seconds, and I would like extend further. I have added command in below way,

```
 ruby_block "#{host_short_name}_reg_chef_node" do
      block do
            puts "Registering Chef Node #{host_full_name}"
          _command = "cd #{node['nodeManager']['app']['base_dir']}; #{node['nodeManager']['knife']['binary']} bootstrap --sudo #{host_full_name}"
          _command += " --ssh-user #{node['nodeManager']['admin']['user']} --no-host-key-verify --identity-file #{node['nodeManager']['admin']['keyfile']}"
          _command +=" --environment #{params[:environment]} --run-list 'role[#{params[:role_hash]['role']}]'"
          puts _command
      vsphere_output = Mixlib::ShellOut.new(_command, :timeout => 10000)
      vsphere_output.run_command
      puts "Output: #{vsphere_output.stdout}"
      puts "Error : #{vsphere_output.stderr}"
    end
      action :nothing
  end
```

and I suspect it is not respecting timeout value. Please advise.

Comment: Please add the Ruby error traceback you get from the debugging information.

Comment: I am not seeing any error or warning, but not considering this timeout value and command returning back after 600 seconds.

Comment: How are you using it and is it possible there is something else triggering a timeout like whichever tool is running Chef?

Comment: If it returns with no output then it seems to be succeeding or being killed elsewhere. Shellout throws an exception if it gets to the timeout, so you'd see something from that as I'd imagine the exception would bubble up and half the chef client. Probably good to post your entire block.

Comment: As directed by you, I have updated my entire resource block